# ConfigurationManager class. ConfigurationSection properties cannot be edited when locked

Tags: c#, .net

Here is code:

```
// These is works
Console.WriteLine(Properties.Settings.Default.name);

Configuration configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = configFile.AppSettings.Settings;
settings.Add("Port", "12");
// Here it fails
configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Content of app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="name" serializeAs="String">
                <value>dasdqweqw</value>
            </setting>
        </ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/></startup></configuration>
```

Can not understand why it is not working. Code is right or I am doing something wrong? On the line configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified); it throws an exception "ConfigurationSection properties cannot be edited when locked."

What scenario I have decided to follow:
1. Via Solution explorer I am opening project properties page (Solution explorer > context menu of project node > Properties), then via Settings tab in project properties page I am creating project's application settings (value of Scope parameter is User). This creates Properties class (located in Settings.Designer.cs file) in namespace of the project & corresponding class properties. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/cftf714c%28v=vs.90%29
2. To create user specific user.config file I have to change added settings & call Properties.Settings.Default.Save() method. If I just call Properties.Settings.Default.Save() without changing settings first this does not create user.config file.

Usage exmple:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.updateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

Console.WriteLine((Properties.Settings.Default.updateTime - DateTime.UtcNow).Hours);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Content of user.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <coonfoo.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="updateTime" serializeAs="String">
                <value>06/03/2018 10:42:03</value>
            </setting>
        </coonfoo.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think you are doing it right, only change you need is to get the correct configuration file. You need to change the `exe.config` file. The way to do that is use `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)` that should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Configuration roaming = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
        ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = roaming.FilePath;
        Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = configuration.AppSettings.Settings;
        settings.Add("Port", "12");
        configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    }
}
```

Found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134265(v=vs.110).aspx) which might help you.